# Sorting numerical data from text file high to low (Python)

Tags: python, sorting

I have saved various scores to a text file using Python. Here is how the text file is structured (the name of the text file is class_a.txt):

```
Ben,10
Harry,4
Joe,6
Adam,7
Anthony,10
```

I have managed to sort the scores alphabetically, here is the code for that:

```
def alpha():
    if class_name == "a":
        with open("class_a.txt") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            lines = sorted(lines)
            for line in lines:
                name = line[:line.find(",")]
                marks = line[line.find(",")+1:].split(",")
                marks = sorted(marks)
                print(name + "'s Score = " + marks[-1])
```

This code outputs the scores like this:

```
Adam's Score = 7    
Anthony's Score = 10    
Ben's Score = 10    
Harry's Score = 4   
Joe's Score = 6
```

However I would also like to add an option to sort the scores from highest to lowest.

For example when Python outputs the data from the text file, it will look like this:

```
Anthony's Score = 10    
Ben's Score = 10    
Adam's Score = 7    
Joe's Score = 6 
Harry's Score = 4
```

Comment: OP, please do not vandalize or deface your own question. Questions on SO are for posterity, so removing them once you got an answer is not permitted and also very selfish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more Pythonic way of achieving what you're after:

```
import csv

with open("class_a.txt") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    sorted_list = sorted(csv_reader, key=lambda row: int(row[1]), reverse=True)

for name, score in sorted_list:
    print("{0}'s Score = {1}".format(name, score))
```

Output:

```
Ben's Score = 10
Anthony's Score = 10
Adam's Score = 7
Joe's Score = 6
Harry's Score = 4
```

By using the `csv` module, you are able to generate an array for each row in the file and use `sorted` to sort the list generated based on a specific column.

Answer (score 2):

You just need:

```
def alpha():
    if class_name == "a":
        with open("class_a.txt") as f:
            lines = sorted([i.strip().split(',') for i in f], 
                           key=lambda x: (-int(x[1]), x[0]),
                           reverse=True)

            for name, score in lines:
                 print(name + "'s Score = " + score)
```

Demo:

```
Anthony's Score = 10
Ben's Score = 10
Adam's Score = 7
Joe's Score = 6
Harry's Score = 4
```

Comment: If you want to sort on score and then name (when two names are tied), use `key = lambda x: (int(x[1]),x[0])`

Comment: @Matthew: Ahhh, I forgot that part. But however, your code is correct but doesn't work, output is the same...let me find why.

Comment: @Matthew: Understand, blame `reverse=True`. Wait me fix this.